# Infinite direct product of the integers not a free module over the integers

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it true that, as Z-modules, the polynomial ring and the power series ring over integers are dual to each other?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-ring-over)

Is there an easy proof? I only found citations but have no access. By the way: If we cross over to the rationals every vector space is free (using Zorn's lemma). But can one construct a basis of "Countable infinite product of the rationals"?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of (more precisely, a consequence of) 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-ring-over/10249#10249

Answer (score 9):

It is known (this is Specker's theorem) that the natural map
$$\iota :\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb N} \ \mathbb Z \to Hom_{\mathbb Z} \left( \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z,\mathbb Z \right)$$
is an isomorphism of abelian groups.

In particular, $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ cannot be a free abelian group. The crucial part of the proof appeared [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37223/ultraproducts-of-finite-cyclic-groups/37249#37249). Also interesting: Nöbeling showed that the abelian group of bounded sequences in $\mathbb Z$ is free as an abelian group.

Answer (score 4):

This paper addresses the question
http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~schroeer/publications_pdf/infinite_product-1.pdf

Also there is a wiki link 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baer%E2%80%93Specker_group

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it counts as "easy", but a proof of this result appears as some notes in the American Mathematical Monthly, [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly_aug_sep08_toc.html).

Comment: Someone voted this answer down. May I ask why? 

Answer (score 2):

See Example 3.5 at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/dualmod.pdf for an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another reference to a proof of Specker's theorem is [Zagier's St Andrews problems](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/Zagier/Problems.html).

**Added**
Also rings such as $\mathbb{Z}$ with this property are called
[slender rings](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-49/issue-2/Slender-rings-and-modules/pjm/1102945104.full).